# Oracle SQL Plus: Error “ORA-00922: missing or invalid option” when creating user

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

This is my first time to use SQLPlus and Oracle. (exploring other DBMS) :)

Using SQL Plus, I'm trying to create user.

```
SQL> create user <username> identified by <password>;
```

But it shows error:

```
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

What do I missed?

:(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the oracle DOCS:

> Nonquoted identifiers must begin with an alphabetic character from your database character set. Quoted identifiers can begin with any character.

so its good practice to use quotes around the password!

ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm

Comment: Thanks! user created. :D